# Java Web Development Starter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have much experience of working as a web programmer in PHP with kohana, cakephp, codeigniter and symfony2 framework. I know Jquery, AJAX, JavaScript. During my studies I took one java course but it was fully core java. I want to dirty my hands in java web development with some framework.

I need some suggestions from where to start and what should be my 1st step. I know OOP concepts and java syntax but not familiar with web related stuff.

Some cool books, blogs, tutorials and suggestions about the selection of framework will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse is the most used tool, many plugins exist for it.

Answer (score 3):

Java EE
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc

Java Tutorial
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

General Java Stuff
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/overview/gettingstarted-jsp-138588.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/webapps-1-138794.html

About the Class Path
http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Answer (score 1):

Hey dude first you concentrate on core java i.e J2SE
  in J2SE learn

- Collection Framework
- Threads
- Exception Handling
- OOPs Concepts

  later concentrate on J2EE core concepts
- Servlets
- jsp

later think about Framework

Comment: will it not take too much time ? I already know java and OOP concept

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I started with Google's top links. Then, I discovered [SpringFuse](http://www.springfuse.com/):

- [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
- [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)
- [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/)
- Spring MVC
- Et cætera...

To sum up: most common tools well configured and ready-to-use.

Answer (score 0):

Start with JAVAEE  core concepts as thing you know core java.. study Servlet(as they are the father of maximum things)..study JSP...study difference between webserver and application server...finally dirty ur hands with MVC (Spring3 or Struts2) depending on ur choice..This is I think a better approach..please correct me if I am wrong anywhere..

Comment: Do u know any good tutorials which more practical as I dont like o study too much theory :p

Comment: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/ and Google..only hope...Personally I think if u read few initial chapter of j2ee complete reference ..then ur good to start with..otherwise you will be lost in J2EE world..choice is urs..

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly, I'd wait for september - JavaEE 7 is coming and they want to rapidly change some basic things, you might also just wait for a little while, since JavaEE 7 will focs mainly on cloud integration. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

The above information is pretty good to start,but do keep in mind using a good intelligent IDE would definitely help to learn quickly and do have look at debugging capability tools like LOG4J.Debugging plays a important role in web  applications.
Mkyong tutorials and vannila.com examples on frameworks are easy guides to start examples.hope that helps.Happy coding.